# Return an error if HTMLPurifier could not parse a string?

Tags: php, html, htmlpurifier

I can't seem to figure out the most basic part of a PHP library. How do you check if it returned an error or not?

I'm using a library called HTMLPurifier to sanitize user html input for the database, this is what the initiation looks like:

```
require_once '/path/to/HTMLPurifier.auto.php';

$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
$clean_html = $purifier->purify($dirty_html);
```

How do I check if the purifier did anything or returned an error? Something like

```
if (!$clean_html) {
   echo 'Error occured: '.$purifier->error;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what kind of errors you want the system to report, the [`Core.CollectErrors`](http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html#Core.CollectErrors) directive may be what you're looking for:

> Whether or not to collect errors found while filtering the document. This is a useful way to give feedback to your users. **Warning**: Currently this feature is very patchy and experimental, with lots of possible error messages not yet implemented. It will not cause any problems, but it may not help your users either.

You would use it like this:

```
require_once '/path/to/HTMLPurifier.auto.php';

$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$config->set('Core', 'CollectErrors', true);
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
$clean_html = $purifier->purify($dirty_html);

$error_collector = $purifier->context->get('ErrorCollector');
echo $error_collector->getHTMLFormatted($config);
```

You can see error collection in use in this example script: https://repo.or.cz/htmlpurifier-web.git/blob/b4f116b5aebdc688e6e4b458d5a790add6282cd5:/demo.php

See if that's what you need?